# Sequent's NFC Platform

Tags: android, mobile, nfc, payment-services

During my research about NFC platforms I found this Sequent platform that claims to provide a secure element manager that can be accessed by applications.

I could not find, though,  any "real life" information such as devices and operating systems that are compatible or even demo/fake apps to run and test if it really works... I would love to make some Android app demo but I don't even know where to start (if it is at all possible)..

Does anybody here has more info on that?? Has anybody seen it working???

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this with any of the Google Nexus phones that have NFC. Access to the content of the Secure Element is controlled by Google. To access the API that e.g. Google Wallet uses, you need a rooted phone. To replace this API with something else, such as perhaps this Sequent platform, you would need to build a custom ROM.